# Simple insert in PHP5

Tags: php, mysql, oop

am trying to learn about `oop php` best practice  and it's difficult just to debug , i know this is maybe a duplicated question and am hoping not to get a lot of negative votes so let's get to the problem :

I have a `Product` class in `Products.php`

```
class Product {

    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $price;    
    public $description;

    function __construct($id, $name, $price, $description)
    {
        $this->$id = $id; 
        $this->$name = $name;
        $this->$price = $price;
        $this->$description = $description;

    }  
}
```

a `ProductManger` class in `ProductsManager.php`

```
include('Products.php');
include('config.php');

class ProductManager {


function addProduct($conn,Products $p)
{

  $query="INSERT INTO `products`( `name`, `description`, `price`) VALUES    ('".$name."','".$price."','".$description."')";
    $c->exec($query);

}   
 }
```

a `config` Class in `config.php`

```
class config {

    function connect() {

        $serverName="localhost";
        $dbName="phppoo";
        $user="root";
        $pass="";

        return $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$serverName;dbname=$dbName",$user,$pass);
    }   
} 
//to be clear i think there are no issue related to connection
```

a Html page Where i submit the form

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

 <body>
 <form action="AddProduct.php" method="POST">
 <table border="3">
 <tr>
    <td>Reference<td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Nom<td>
    <td><input type="text" name="desc"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>date de création <td>
    <td><input type="number" name="price"></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td> <td>
     <td><input type="submit" name="ajouter" value="ajouter"></td>
   </tr>


 </form>
 </table>   


 </body>
 </html>
```

and finally the `AddProduct.php` Where i instantiate the product manager and send data so i can Execute the `query`

```
include('ProductsManager.php');

$co = new config();
$c=$co->connect();


if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_POST['desc'])and isset($_POST['price']) ) {
    $p=new ProductManager($_POST['name'],$_POST['desc'],$_POST['price']); 
    $p->addProduct($c,$p);
}
```

now if  i try to submit the `form` from the `html` page ,am redirected to a blank page`AddProduct.php` and it's normal cause am not returning a value.

the problem here is , am not getting the new values submitted inserted in  my `Database`.

Thanks to any help , PS: if you think this isn't the best practice please mention a better method or a tuto. Thank you

Comment: Look at your ProductManager::addProduct method.  What are `$c`, `$name`, `$price`, `$description`, `$querry` in this function's context?  They don't exist.  You also have price and description flipped around once you get that figured out.  Lots of problems, too broad of a question for Stackoverflow.  It shouldn't be any harder to debug, enable error reporting and start correcting one error at a time.

Comment: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. This should be done first-thing, and not "later", as bugs introduced by doing it the sloppy way often prevent you from getting your code working properly. Passing some arguments to `execute` is not hard, and should be the way you do these things every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the property within a class you do this:

```
$this->price = $price;
```

Not this:

```
$this->$price = $price;
```

What the above does is try to the property based on the value of $price. So if price is `5.0` it will look for the property of `$this->5.0`.

Your updated class would look like so:

```
class Product {

    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $price;    
    public $description;

    function __construct($id, $name, $price, $description)
    {
        $this->id = $id; 
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->description = $description;

    }  
}
```

Your add product method would look like this:

```
function addProduct($conn,Products $p) {

    $query="INSERT INTO `products`( `name`, `description`, `price`) VALUES    ('".$p->name."','".$p->description."','".$p->price."')";
    $conn->exec($query);

}
```

The properties on the `$p` variable were not being accessed and must be accessed like `$p->yourProperty`.  Description and price were also in the incorrect locations.

There are additional issues related to SQL injection which are not being covered within this answer but at the very least this will help you to see what is wrong with the OOP itself.

The last error is that you want to call `addProduct` from the instance (`$p`) of the ProductManager class and pass an instance of the `Product` variable to the addProduct method:

```
$p = new ProductManager(); 
$product = new Product(-1, $POST['name'],$POST['desc'],$POST['price']);
$p->addProduct($c, $product);
```

I set `-1` for the $id parameter since the row hasn't been inserted yet.  After the insert you would likely want to get the last row insert id and assign it to the instance property, e.g., `$this->id = $lastInsertId;`

and, you need to fix your `if` statement:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_POST['desc'])and isset($_POST['price']) ) {
```

It is `$_POST` not `$POST_`... we were not seeing the result of the statement so we did not see any errors related to the OO code.

Comment: thank you Smith for the answer , i tried fixing in like you told me too , but no result the isn't inserted in the database , also i figure it out that it's `$_POST['desc']`  not like i write it .

Comment: Do you get an error?  Did update how addProduct is called using the $product variable?

Comment: am not getting any error do you have an idea how can debug this !!

Comment: I found another unusual error which I've added to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Yeah i fixed  that one , look Smith i really appreciate what you've done but i think it's really messed up am going to accept your question but could you please , tell me how to debug , thank you

Comment: I would do a var_dump of each individual variable to see what is wrong. For example, do a var_dump of `$p` and make sure it is showing you the value you expect.  e.g, `var_dump($p);` .. you may also want to do print or echo statements within the if-block to see if it correctly seeing the matching condition.

Answer (score 2):

Modify insert statement as this way. Because you can access product property with references.

```
$query="INSERT INTO `products`( `name`, `description`, `price`) VALUES  
('".$p['name']."','".$p['description']."','".$p['price']."')";
```

Comment: That is for SDO (Service Data Objects)...look more closely at the documentation.  Test out this code for yourself `$b = new stdClass(); $b['foo'] = 123;`.  Sent some up votes to some of your past answers, cheers.

Comment: Thank you very much